# UILabel In UICollectionViewCell is setting after scrolling?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my code,I was trying to use `UIImage` & `UIabel` in `UICollectionViewCell`.What I was doing If there is no image in `UICollectionViewCell` i want to shift `UILabel` upwards.So I used two frames of label and checked for `if(UIImageView.image==nil)` it is showing effect after scrolling?
What to do?
Here is the code what i did-

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UICollectionViewCell *myCell=(UICollectionViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
myCell = [collectionView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[myCell viewWithTag:12];

UIImageView *collectionViewImage=(UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:11];



NSString *collectionViewImageName=[imagesCollectionViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
collectionViewImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:collectionViewImageName];


if (collectionViewImage.image==nil) {

[collectionViewImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(35, 73, 309, 54)];
 label.text=[lableColectionviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return myCell;
}else {

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 294, 352, 49)];
label.text=[lableColectionviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return myCell;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove cell contentView subviews every collectionView

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

method call.

use

```
for([UIView  *view in cell.contentView.subViews]){
    [view removeFromSuperView];
    view=nil;
}
```

and replace this line of code
UICollectionViewCell *myCell=(UICollectionViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

With

UICollectionViewCell *myCell=nil;

Comment: AFTER THIS ADD SUBVIEWS TO CONTENT VIEW OF TABLECELL